# addAttributeToSort() not working

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-options, sorting

I have configurable product create with attribute size, I try to list this attribute size in the product description, but addAttributeToSort() not working. My code is:

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);

    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('size','ASC')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
```

right now I have something like this:

```
100g
10g
25g
```

[image]

If I use **DESC** instead **ASC** I have this sorting:

```
25g
10g
100g
```

The entire code:

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);

    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('size','ASC')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        echo $simple_product->getAttributeText('size');
    }
endif;
```

[image]

Comment: this is right sorting, because its a string sorting, because in your dropdown attribute you have set values with `g` so it takes string instead of integer

Comment: thank you but how I can change this to have the correct sorting?

Comment: go to `catalog->manage attribute` and  search for size and change the dropdown option value

Comment: please take a look I add an image to see the size attribute

Comment: remove `g` from name and your sort will work fine on frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `size` is a dropdown attribute.
I'm not sure exactly how the sorting works but it can be one of the 2 cases.

Case 1.
The sorting is done via values of that attribute. And the actual values stored in the database for are integers. They are the ids of the options.
So most probably the id of the option `100g` is smaller than the id of the option `10g` and the sorting is done for these ids.

Case 2.
The sorting is done somehow by using the labels of the options.
In this case, what you see in the result is perfectly normal since the comparison is done for strings and the string `100g` is "smaller" than the string `10g`.

Either way, I propose you a solution that works in both cases.
Since you need only to display the labels somewhere, why not just collect the labels as you do now, add them to an array and then sort that array as you want.
Again, you might hit the problem that the array elements will be sorted as strings, but you can overcome this by removing `g` from the end of each element, sorting then adding `g` back.

Here is the code you can use.
It works for kg and g at the same time and it sorts them properly.
I mean 1500g comes between 1kg and 2kg.

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);

    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('size','ASC')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    $toSort = array();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product) {
        $unit = trim($simple_product->getAttributeText('size'));
        //check of it's kg unit
        if (substr($unit, -2) == 'kg') {
            $toSort[] = array(
                'sort_value' => (float)str_replace('kg', '', $unit) * 1000, 
                'real_value' => $unit,
                'product' => $simple_product
            );
        } else {
            //it's gram unit
            $toSort[] = array(
                'sort_value' => (float)str_replace('g', '', $unit), 
                'real_value' => $unit,
                'product' => $simple_product
            );
        }
    }
    usort($toSort, function($a, $b){
        if ($a['sort_value'] == $b['sort_value']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['sort_value'] < $b['sort_value']) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    foreach ($toSort as $item) {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $product = $item['product'];
        //use getFinalPrice instead of price. Maybe there are discount rules applied to it.
        echo $item['real_value'].': '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice()).'<br />';
    }
endif;
```

Comment: Hi Marius thank you, can you tell me please or show me an example how I can do this with my code?

Comment: aaa now I understand what you say, to remove that g letter from size attribute, hmm is not a good idea, I can't do this, that must be there because I have kg too

Comment: maybe you can transform everything to grams by multiplying with 1000 the values that have `kg`. Then transform them back after sorting. Not sure about the way to go.

Comment: yes I know, is the only way? this can be done only in this way?

Comment: I didn't claim this is the only way to do it, but I don't know any other way. And it's going to be complicated to sort them if you have kg and g at the same time. Maybe split them into 2 arrays one for g and one for kg, sort each one and merge them again

Comment: I understand Marius, thank you so much, I really appreciate your efforts

Comment: I remove the g and now I have something like this: 10 / 100 / 25, so is not a solution to remove the g

Comment: sort what you have and add g back.

Comment: I don't understand very well

Comment: you should have an array like this `$sizes = array(10, 100, 25)`. Call `sort($sizes)` then add the g back to all elements. $realSizes = array_map(funcion($item){return $item.'g'}); Then use the `$realSizes` array where you need them

Comment: can you put this on my code please I don't understand very well

Comment: please take a look I add my entire code here at the very bottom of my post.

Comment: hold your horses. I'm working on it.

Comment: @RobertD see my update.

Comment: it's work perfect, thank you very much, you're the one

Comment: one small request, where I need to add this to have the price too? 
echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice());

Comment: See my edit and watch out for typos and syntax errors. I didn't test the code.

Comment: it's work perfect, I don't know how I can tell you in few words how helpful is your answer, thank you again so much

Comment: the only thing that I found is when I add this in a list the last </li> 100g is not aligned like the others, I edit my post to add an image maybe you have an idea but is not so important, I don;t want to abuse of your kindness

Comment: it may be because of the difference in number of letters. You can try to add some styling around your elements spans or divs with fixed width.

Comment: indeed, where I need to add a div for size attribute?

Comment: I do something like this and is okay  echo '<div class="attribute">' . $item['real_value']. '</div>'

Comment: Hi Marius, can you tell me something please? Is there anyway to sort this DESC, now is 10,25,100 for example we can do this 100,25,10? Thank you

Comment: @Marius, how this can be done in Magento2 ? I am using Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer aroundGetProductCollection plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
        $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);

    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

    $simple_collection->setOrder('size', 'ASC');
```

Comment: what does sku have to do with what the OP is asking?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you do here, but is the same thing like in my code.

Comment: your code is not work,  I have tried addSort/setSort and also unshiftSort and none of them change anything.

Answer (score 0):

this is right sorting, because its a `string` sorting, because in your `dropdown attribute` you have set values with `g`so it sort as  string instead of integer

go to `catalog->manage attribute` and search for `size` and change the `dropdown` option value

remove `g` from all options and your sort will work fine.

Comment: if you take a look at my discussion with Marius, I just tell him the same thing, I remove the g and is the same, please take a look I add my entire code here at the very bottom of my post.